# Python3 pydantic model serialization

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic, tortoise-orm

I have the following tortoise ORM setup and corresponding pydantic models:

```
class Chat(models.Model):
    id = fields.UUIDField(pk=True)

    class Meta:
        table = "chat"

    class PydanticMeta:
        pass

class ChatHistory(models.Model):
    id = fields.UUIDField(pk=True)
    chat: fields.ForeignKeyRelation["Chat"] = fields.ForeignKeyRelation("models.Chat",
                                                                         index=True,
                                                                         related_name="messages")
    content: str = fields.TextField()

    class Meta:
        table = "chat_history"
        indexes = ["chat"]

    class PydanticMeta:
        exclude = ["chat"]

Chat_Pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(Chat, name="Chat")
```

And I have a fastapi where I want to have two endpoints, one should give back a list of all `Chat` with the `messages` field contained and one without. At least from my understanding the best way to achieve this is to add some sort of different serializers to the `Chat`. But how can I create `N` different serializers and use them in a fastapi endpoint flexibly?